# Search by location using an array with geokit gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geokit

I need to search on two or more locations

```
model = Model.in_range("0".."5",:origin => [LatLng, LatLng, LatLng, LatLng)
```

is posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain multiple calls like:

```
model = Model.in_range("0".."5",:origin => [Lat1, Lng1]).in_range("0".."5",:origin => [Lat2, Lng2])
```

For deep reference, check the method at https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails/blob/3a7b4e1083dd06d486307ebf71c36608186c8d73/lib/geokit-rails/acts_as_mappable.rb#L134

Comment: hello i need a acumulate ranges example have two locations and i need search nearby on lat 1 and lat2 and result in 1 query